# Universal Image Loader and 302 redirects

Tags: universal-image-loader

Using UIL version 1.8.0 to load a twitter profile image url:
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/smashingmag.jpg?size=bigger

with disc and memory cache. The images are failing to load and storing the html that comes along with the 302 redirect in the disc cache file. The images never load or decode successfully (the onLoadingFailed method of my SimpleImageLoadingListener gets called for every twitter profile image url). Can anyone load a simple twitter image url with UIL?

Here is the content of my cache file for that url:

cat /mnt/sdcard/MyCache/CacheDir/1183818163

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3056708597/6438618743e2b2d7d663fd43412bdae8_bigger.png">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Here is my configuration:

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(FrequencyApplication.getContext(), "MyCache/CacheDir");

DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
    .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(FrequencyApplication.getContext())
    .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800)
    .threadPoolSize(20)
    .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
    .offOutOfMemoryHandling()
    .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
    .discCache(new TotalSizeLimitedDiscCache(cacheDir, 30 * 1024 * 1024))
    .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
    .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(MyApplication.getContext(), 20 * 1000, 30 * 1000))
    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
    .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `HttpURLConnection` can't handle redirect from HTTP to HTTPS automatically ([link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4620571)). I'll fix it in next lib version.

Fix for now - extend `BaseImageDownloader` and set it into configuration:

```
public class MyImageDownloader implements BaseImageDownloader {
    @Override
    protected InputStream getStreamFromNetwork(URI imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUri.toURL().openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        conn.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        conn.connect();
        while (conn.getResponseCode() == 302) { // >=300 && < 400
            String redirectUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(redirectUrl).openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
            conn.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
            conn.connect();
        }
        return new FlushedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the problem. And your fix works great.

Comment: It is giving conn.getResponseCode() == 500